# Open Source Package Name

Tags: community

I have found this useful package for cloud native applications.

It's name and site is [Kuma](https://github.com/kumahq/kuma) .

The problem is that, the name(Kuma) is a very sensitive organ in my language. A womans private part, (Swahili version).

From their website, that name means Bear in Japanese.

Is it possible to request a name change?

If yes, what are the ways to proceed in asking for a name change?

I think using Issues pane is not good for this kind of claims.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to request a name change?

Sure, you can request almost anything.

> If yes, what are the ways to proceed in asking for a name change?

The best is probably to contact one of the project admins privately and sound them out as to whether they would consider a name change; you do this privately because doing it as a public issue on Github is likely to produce more noise than value.

However, be very prepared for the admins to say "sorry, we're happy with the current name". Bringing this back to open source briefly, you of course have the option to create your own fork of the project with a different name; if the community believe that your name is more appropriate, they can then choose to move their efforts onto your fork rather than the original.

Comment: Ohoo, I like the approach method